# Input of different data types seperated by a space

Tags: java, input

I want to input a integer number and then after a space, same number of alphabets without space each of I have to process individually(like elements of character array).

Comment: can you explaine more please, you question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the specifications you described, something like this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class DiffDataTypes{

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int integerNum = sc.nextInt(); // input a integer number                                                                                                                               
            char charArray[] = new char[integerNum]; // same number of alphabets without space each processed individually(like elements of character array)                                       

            charArray = sc.next().toCharArray();

            System.out.print(integerNum + " : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < integerNum; i++)
                System.out.print(charArray[i]);

            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Input:

```
3 happy
```

Output:

```
3 : hap
```